# Google Translate font tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

When I start translating on my web page (right click -> Translate to English), and then click on submit button on my form, the text in the button is multiplied. I realised that google translate wraps text in my button in double font tags, and if I click on the button more than one time, the text will mulitply.

Here is code before translation:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-ox btn-block btn-spin"> 
  Update app details
</button>
```

After translatation and clicking on button 3 times:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-ox btn-block btn-spin">

  <font><font class="">
    Update app details
  </font></font>

  <font><font>
    Update app details
  </font></font>

  <font><font>
    Update app details
  </font></font>
</button>
```

I am interested if there is way to intercept a function that adds font tags, or somehow to not add font tags at all?

Comment: $("button.btn").remove("font"); on page load

Comment: thanks, but it's happening on every route, and i don't want to hardcode all selectors that i need to remove. also, text multiplies with numbers of click on it. As I sad, I want to know if there is some function that is doing that, attaching on text and wrapping it into font tag